# Make a loop in python with column names and index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As a beginner, I have a simple question on how make a loop in python. Right now, I have a code like this:

```
    value1 = df[df.name == 'name1'].col1
    exp1 = math.exp(value1)/(1 + math.exp(value1))
    exp1

    value2 = df[df.name == 'name1'].col2
    exp2 = math.exp(value2)/(1 + math.exp(value2))
    exp2
....
    value10 = df[df.name == 'name1'].col10
    exp10 = math.exp(value10)/(1 + math.exp(value10))
    exp10

# where: `df` is the dataframe, `name` is the column name, `name1` is the column value. 
# `predict1` is also a column name, and there are 10 such columns i.e., from col1 - col10.
```

First, I want to compute these with a loop.

Then, I want to make a table like this:

```
exp1 a # just a random value calculated above.
exp2 b
exp3 c
# where, a b c are just a random value calculated above.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `groupby`

```
s=df.groupby('name')['col1'...'col10'].apply(lambda x  : math.exp(x)/(1 + math.exp(x))
```